# How do i stream an audio from a database and play on a phone when i retrieve the link using fetch api?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, html5-audio

I currently have the following in my html

```
<audio id="result-audio"></audio>
<button onclick = "playBack()"><i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i></button>
```

In my javascript i have the following

```
 fetch(`${url}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        document.getElementById("result-audio").setAttribute("src", `${data['File']}`);
})

function playBack(){
    document.getElementById("result-audio").play();
}
```

where url goes to a database and retrieves a link for an audio file which is inserted into the source of the audio element. Retrieving the link works fine and clicking the button the file plays ok on a laptop but it does not on any phone. How best can i solve the issue of it not playing on the phone or is there another approach i need to take?

**EDIT**
I am not looking to make an audio player. I am looking for example the audio you get when you search the meaning of a word on google where it pronounces that word.

Comment: Maybe its my laptop host that is the issue. I am using xampp

Comment: Thank You @Yogi, the issue was the way i am storing the link to the file. After using remote debug i figured out that the database link points to http://localhost/app/audio/file.mp3. So it was trying to go to localhost. Will now have to figure out how to store the link during development

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play audio on both desktop and mobile devices, you should ensure that the audio format you're using is compatible with a wide range of browsers and devices. You can also use the HTML5 audio element's controls attribute to provide a built-in audio player interface for easier playback on both desktop and mobile.

Here's how you can modify your code:

1. Make sure your audio file is in a widely supported format, such as MP3.
2. Modify your HTML to include the controls attribute for the audio element:

```html
<audio id="result-audio" controls></audio>
<button onclick="playBack()"><i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i></button>
```

```js
function playBack() {
  const audioElement = document.getElementById("result-audio");
  if (audioElement.paused) {
    audioElement.play();
  } else {
    audioElement.pause();
  }
}

// Use the 'loadedmetadata' event to start playing once the audio is loaded
fetch(`${url}`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const audioElement = document.getElementById("result-audio");
    audioElement.setAttribute("src", `${data['File']}`);
    audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
      playBack(); // Start playing once audio is loaded
    });
  });
```

Comment: The audio element will not be visible on the page so having controls for it would not be ok. Also the audio will be a few seconds long so no need to have controls. Its for pronunciations of words like those you get from google. All files will be saved as mp3

Comment: You must play the audio after you get the response, you can't just assign the src attribute with the audio source, you must play it because you will have no controls.

Comment: I have edited the code accordingly but it still wont play on phones. Could the host be a factor? I am using xampp

Comment: It could be the host, you could launch the project on the ip of your local network, but it strikes me the fact that the problem is the CORS of the page, what errors or warnings do they show you?